# How to find corrupted files?

Tags: filesystem, data-recovery, hard-drive

Some files on my hard drive are corrupted (no worries, nothing system-related, just a junk of data files, mp3 etc.). I found that out when I tried to burn them all to a DVD, the burning application show a message that it cannot read the files as they are corrupted. [This is probably a drive issue, it had happened me once or twice already].

I don't care about recovering them, but I have to determine which ones are corrupted. I cannot check by manually opening them all, as there are thousands of them. **Is there any tricky way to check all the files and list the ones that may cause problems when tried to open?**

Comment: What type or filesystem are those files in? What application are you using to burn them?

Comment: Try this: copy all those files to another location in your hard disk to see if the corrupted ones are "left behind", i.e., not copied, but you can copy the rest of them....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do what luri suggested (copy the files somewhere else). then, use a diff tool like meld (`sudo apt-get install meld`) will be very helpful by doing a directory comparison between the original and the copy. you can filter out the identical files, and only see the differences. That's how I found some files corrupting a sync recently.